# .NET 7 OutputCache Vary On Part of URL

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0

I'm trying to better understand OutputCaching and have an API endpoint in the format of:

/data/{firstParam}/values/{secondParam}

I'm trying to create an CustomCachePolicy to cache responses purely based on the secondParam so:

- /data/1/values/0
- /data/2/values/0

Will both access the same cache record, as I don't care about the first parameter changing. Conversely the following:

- /data/1/values/0
- /data/2/values/1

Should be stored differently in the cache.

I've setup a CustomCache Policy as follows:

```
internal class CustomCachePolicy : IOutputCachePolicy
{
    public ValueTask CacheRequestAsync(OutputCacheContext context, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        context.EnableOutputCaching = true;
        context.AllowCacheLookup = true;
        context.AllowCacheStorage = true;
        context.AllowLocking = true;

        context.ResponseExpirationTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public ValueTask ServeFromCacheAsync(OutputCacheContext context, CancellationToken cancellation) => ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    public ValueTask ServeResponseAsync(OutputCacheContext context, CancellationToken cancellation) => ValueTask.CompletedTask; 
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's possible to configure it in such a way to cache in the way I've described above. **Also** is it possible to do this without an CustomPolicy?

**EDIT 1:**

I think I can achieve this affect by editing the context.HttpContext.Request.Path to remove the parameter since it represents the Key in the cache but I assume there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you could move the arguements to query part, VaryOnQuery would work for you,here's a related issue on github:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48066